# How to change the title of Table of Contents of a Part

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, minitoc

I need to change default title of ToC that `\parttoc` generates, without using `titlesec`package. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\begin{document}

\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{I. MEMORIA}
\parttoc

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}

\end{document}
```

The ToC generates from `\parttoc` would look like:

[image]

I´d like to change the default 'Table of Contents' title for what I want.

Could someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `\ptctitle`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}

\renewcommand\ptctitle{My PTC}

\begin{document}

\doparttoc

\tableofcontents

\part{I. MEMORIA}
\parttoc

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1.1}
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section2.1}

\end{document}
```

[image]